# a question regarding wronskian

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

I was working on following problem:

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be solutions of

> $$x^2y'' + y' + (\sin x)y = 0$$

satisfying

$$y_1(0) = 0, y_1'(0)=1,y_2(0) = 1, y_2'(0)=0 $$.

I worked like following:

since wronskian $W$ is given as $$W = ce^{-\int-\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx}~,$$ wronskian is not zero except the point $x=0$. Thus, The two given solutions are L.I. and hence $y_1$ and  $y_2$ do not have common zeroes. Am I right in concluding this? Kindly rectify if somehwere I went wrong. Thanks for giving time.

Comment: Are your hypothesis correct ? If we write your differential equation for $y_1$ and put $x=0$, this gives $1=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question looks incomplete and unanswered for a long time: but guessing from OP's attempt, I think (s)he is trying to find the Wronskian.

Here's couple of hints that will help you solve the question:

1. $y_1(0) = 0, y_1'(0)=1,y_2(0) = 1, y_2'(0)=0 $. What does that tell you about $W_{(y_1,y_2)}(0)$ ($W_{(y_1,y_2)}(x)=\left|\begin{matrix}y_1(x) &&y_2(x)\\y'_1(x) && y'_2(x)\end{matrix}\right|$)?
2. A little $\color{red}{\text{correction}}$ and $\color{green}{\text{added details}}$ into [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity#Statement_of_Abel.27s_identity) which you seem to have used in your attempt:

$$W(x)=\color{green}{W(0)}\times \color{red}{e^{-\int_0^x \frac1{x^2}dx}}=?$$